# Ansible need to make a json list with variables substituted

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I have this json file:

```
}
  "retry_join": ["192.168.100.11","192.168.100.12","192.168.100.14"],
  "server": true,
  "data_dir": "/var/lib/consul",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "enable_syslog": false,
  "datacenter": "Morrisville",
  "rejoin_after_leave": true,
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "bind_addr": "{{ ansible_host }}",
  "advertise_addr": "{{ ansible_host }}"
}
```

I need to replace this line here with an indeterminate number of hosts from an ansible inventory file like this one from the top header (mville):

```
    [mville]
swarm000 ansible_host=192.168.100.11
swarm001 ansible_host=192.168.100.12
swarm002 ansible_host=192.168.100.14

[000servers]
swarm000 ansible_host=192.168.100.11

[001servers]
swarm001 ansible_host=192.168.100.12

[002-00xservers]
swarm002 ansible_host=192.168.100.14
```

So this line here:

```
"retry_join": ["192.168.100.11","192.168.100.12","192.168.100.14"],
```

would need to get filled by ansible but I don't know how many hosts their could be so it would need to have the commas in the right place.

I know how to do a for loop like this in ansible:

```
{% for host in groups['000servers'] %}
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none   @{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_host'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

how could I apply that?

Thanks!

Comment: (I have a mismatched curly brace at the top of the json that was just me typing it in after an incomplete cut and paste, it isn't the cause of my issue)

Comment: What have you tried for this exact problem and what did you get instead of the expected output? Or alternatively, what are you missing with your looping through hosts that you demonstrated (albeit for a different thing)?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [filters available in Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html). In particular the `to_json` filter

```
{{ some_variable | to_json }}
```

or the `join` filter

```
{{ list | join(" ") }}
```

should be able to help you template those values correctly.

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track this got me close:
{% set allhosts = [] %}
{% for host in groups['mville'].ansible_host%}
    {% set _ = allhosts.append(host) %}
{% endfor%}

{
  "retry_join": [{{ '\"' + allhosts|join('\", \"' + '\"' )}}],

But I needed to get the ip addresses from ansible_host because I dont have DNS in that site and I needed to have the double quotes.

Answer (score 6):

I had very much the same issue when building consul. One thing ( A bit off topic, but it's worth sharing ) I would suggest to you is: build small templates, say you have 1 template for the consul servers and one for the list of joins. It will make your life easier and it's a bit more flexible. Consul will include the files in alphabetical order.

To answer your question here's what I did:

```
// Join local DC agents
{ 
    "start_join": [ {%for host in groups.dc1 %} {% if hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname'] != inventory_hostname %} "{{hostvars[host]['inventory_hostname']}}" {% if not loop.last %}, {%endif%}{%endif%}{%endfor%}]
}
```

Note, I used the hostnames, but you can simply change `inventory_hostname` with `ansible_host`

Hope that helps, let me know if you want me to be more specific on something.

Comment: Dude thank you so much.  I worked on this forever.  FWIW this is what did it for me:



{
  "retry_join": [ {%for host in groups.mville %} "{{hostvars[host]['ansible_host']}}" {% if not loop.last %}, {%endif%}{%endfor%}],
`
I can't upvote because my reputation is too low but this did it for me!

Comment: Glad this helped you. You should still be able to accept the answer even if you cannot upvote!